# SQLAlchemy Connection to Snowflake with Azure AD Authentication

Tags: sqlalchemy, azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to use the below code to connect to my snowflake account using SQL alchemy. It's not working and my *guess* is that this is because we log in using Azure AD authentication. Any help appreciated.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    
    engine = create_engine(
        'snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/'.format(
            user='xxx',
            password='xxx',
            account='xxx'
            
        )
    )
    try:
        connection = engine.connect()
        results = connection.execute('select current_version()').fetchone()
        print(results[0])
    finally:
        connection.close()
        engine.dispose()
```

The error message:

```
DatabaseError: (snowflake.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB: QB67303.eu-west-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443. Incorrect username or password was specified.
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/4xp6)
```

Comment: How is it not working. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Hi @TafMunyurwa, I've added the error message to the question. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `authenticator='externalbrowser'` option to your connection parameters?  That will then prompt you to log into your SSO provider when python makes a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I went with in the end. Thanks to Mike Walton for getting me on the right track.

```
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(URL(
    account = 'x',
    user = 'x',
    password = 'x',
    database = 'x',
    schema = 'x',
    warehouse = 'x',
    role='x',
    authenticator='externalbrowser'
))

try:
        connection = engine.connect()
        sql_df = pd.read_sql(
                                "Select top 1 * from a.b",
                                con=engine
                                )
        
finally:
        connection.close()
        engine.dispose()
```

Answer (score 2):

Though this is not with sqlalchemy but with the native snowflake sql connector, this works for me:

```
import snowflake.connector

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='<YOUR_USERNAME>',
    account='<YOUR_ACCOUNT ; not always needed>',
    host='<YOUR SF host, ex: xxxxxx.snowflakecomputing.com / xxxxxx.a0.satoricyber.net>',
    authenticator='externalbrowser',
    warehouse='<optional>'
    )
cs = ctx.cursor()
try:
    cs.execute("SELECT * FROM ORGDATA.PUBLIC.CUSTOMERS")
    rows = cs.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
finally:
    cs.close()
ctx.close()
```